# Generate apk using Eclipse + Android + Phonegap

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

A project working properly, generates an apk of approximately 400 kb.

It had to reinstall eclipse and again generated workspace, the project compiles correctly. Generates the file apk but has 200kb. When running the emulator gives error:

**"The application X has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again".**

Logcat shows the following:

```
07-09 00:51:51.332: E/AndroidRuntime(219): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-09 00:51:51.351: E/AndroidRuntime(219): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mobilesoftware.rankingd/com.mobilesoftware.rankingd.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mobilesoftware.rankingd.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44e8c3b0
07-09 00:51:51.351: E/AndroidRuntime(219):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
07-09 00:51:51.351: E/AndroidRuntime(219):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
07-09 00:51:51.351: E/AndroidRuntime(219):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
07-09 00:51:51.351: E/AndroidRuntime(219):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
07-09 00:51:51.351: E/AndroidRuntime(219):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 00:51:51.351: E/AndroidRuntime(219):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-09 00:51:51.351: E/AndroidRuntime(219):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-09 00:51:51.351: E/AndroidRuntime(219):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 00:51:51.351: E/AndroidRuntime(219):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-09 00:51:51.351: E/AndroidRuntime(219):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-09 00:51:51.351: E/AndroidRuntime(219):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-09 00:51:51.351: E/AndroidRuntime(219):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 00:51:51.351: E/AndroidRuntime(219): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mobilesoftware.rankingd.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44e8c3b0
07-09 00:51:51.351: E/AndroidRuntime(219):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
07-09 00:51:51.351: E/AndroidRuntime(219):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
07-09 00:51:51.351: E/AndroidRuntime(219):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
07-09 00:51:51.351: E/AndroidRuntime(219):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-09 00:51:51.351: E/AndroidRuntime(219):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
07-09 00:51:51.351: E/AndroidRuntime(219):  ... 11 more
```

Any ideas to find the solution to the problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The library isn't being linked. Go to "Project > Properties > Android." There should be a box at the bottom that lists what libraries are linked. I would assume there is a red X for you. You'll need to delete and re-add the library to your project.

Comment: This marked only Android 4.03 (api 15) in project build target and nothing in libraries. The mainfest has this configuration file: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />